# NodeJs, Mongodb and Redis app using AWS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redis

What are the steps to deploy a Nodejs app that uses both Redis and MongoDB with AWS?

I have already deployed an EC2 instance that has my nodeJS project on it. As well as a different EC2 instance with my MongoDB server. I am planning to then create a third EC2 instance where I will run my Redis server. My reason for using three separate EC2 instances is that I read that I can not run my MongoDB and Redis servers on the same machine, and using one EC2 instance for each service seemed to be the cleanest approach.

If such an approach is valid, what security group preferences can I use to allow only my nodeJS EC2 instance to access the EC2 instances containing my databases?

Comment: AWS elastiCache has Redis support in case you didn't know. https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/redis/?nc1=h_ls

Comment: Also searching for this